# Working with DOM properties like scrollHeight, scrollTop in shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom, lit-element, lit

working with LitElement and in shadow dom.  I used to have this code in light dom:

```
const {scrollHeight,scrollTop,clientHeight} = document.documentElement;
```

When I switched to using shadow dom, this.shadowRoot.documentElement breaks.
firstElemementChild seems to work.  But is it equivalent?

```
const {scrollHeight,scrollTop,clientHeight} = this.shadowRoot.firstElementChild;
```

What's the best way of working with scrollHeight, scrollTop, etc document properties when in shadowroot?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just using `document.documentElement`?

Comment: oh yes, document.documentElement does indeed still work inside shadow dom.  Initially I saw that document.documentElement was returning null, but I think that was because I had mixed shadow / light dom in the components.  I double checked after reading your comment.  thanks!